# Error in Javascript Promises while trying to create a function in Firebase FireStore

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

so I've been following this 5 part tutorial series as to how notifications can be sent from device to device using Firebase Cloud Storage and the javascript I wrote seems to be incorrect because I keep getting the error that "Each then() should return a value or throw  promise/always-return". Can someone tell me as to how I should correct this?

**index.js**

```
'use-strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore.document("Users/{user_id}/Notifications/{notification_id}").onWrite((event) => {

  var user_id = event.params.user_id;
  var notification_id = event.params.notification_id;

  //console.log("User ID: " + user_id + " | Notification ID : " + notification_id);

  return admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(user_id).collection("Notifications").doc(notification_id).get().then(queryResult => {
    var from_user_id = queryResult.data().from;
    var from_message = queryResult.data().message;

    var from_data = admin.firestore().collection("").doc("from_user_id").get();
    var to_data = admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(user_id).get();

    return Promise.all([from_data, to_data]).then(result => {
      var from_name = result[0].data().name;
      var to_name = result[1].data().name;
      var token_id = result[1].data().token_id;

      console.log("From: " + from_name + " | To : " + to_name);

      var payload = {
        notification : {
          title : "Notification From : " + from_name,
          body : from_message,
          icon : default
        }
      };

      return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload).then(result => {
        console.log("Notification Sent");
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Apart from the above error I also get a "parsing" error as follows

```
32:18 error Parsing error: Unexpected token default
```

Comment: second issue ... `default` is a reserved word in javascript (and undefined in your code anyway)

Comment: first "problem" (warning I'd have thought) - `console.log("Notification Sent");` has no return in that `.then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*"Each then() should return a value or throw promise/always-return"*

This indicates that one of your `.then`'s doesn't return a value (or throw an error)

Here is the culprit:

```
.then(result => {
    console.log("Notification Sent");
});
```

So add a `return`. Now, since `console.log` return value is `undefined` and in a function having no return statement there's an implied `return undefined`

Therefore the code below results in exactly the same behaviour (i.e. `return undefined`), and will prevent that warning message

```
.then(result => {
    return console.log("Notification Sent");
});
```

As far as your error regarding `default`, that's simply because `default` is a reserved word in javascript (and it's not even declared in your code anyway) - it's like trying to use `if` or `while` as a variable name

---

Another potential issue I see in your code is

```
var from_user_id = queryResult.data().from;
var from_message = queryResult.data().message;

//***                                                vvvvvvvvvvvvvv
var from_data = admin.firestore().collection("").doc("from_user_id").get();
var to_data = admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(user_id).get();
```

Should that be `.doc(from_user_id)` - otherwise, what is the point of `var from_user_id = queryResult.data().from;`

---

And finally, as an aside, I see that you are nesting your promises rather than chaining them. One benefit of promises is you can avoid the *"callback pyramid of hell/doom"*

Your code could be written like *below* instead which avoids the "pyramid" - there's also some other ES6/ES7+ tricks in there so that `queryResult.data()` and `to_data.data()` only needs to be called once

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore.document("Users/{user_id}/Notifications/{notification_id}").onWrite((event) => {

    const user_id = event.params.user_id;
    const notification_id = event.params.notification_id;

    return admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(user_id).collection("Notifications").doc(notification_id).get()
    .then(queryResult => {
        const {from:from_user_id, message:from_message} = queryResult.data();

        const from_data = admin.firestore().collection("").doc(from_user_id).get();
        const to_data = admin.firestore().collection("Users").doc(user_id).get();

        return Promise.all([from_data, to_data, from_message]); // added from_message so it's available in the next .then
    })
    .then(([from_data, to_data, from_message]) => { // added from_message
        const from_name = from_data.data().name;
        const {name:to_name, token_id} = to_data.data();

        console.log("From: " + from_name + " | To : " + to_name);

        const payload = {
            notification : {
                title : "Notification From : " + from_name,
                body : from_message,
                icon : 'default'
            }
        };

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(token_id, payload);
    })
    .then(result => {
        return console.log("Notification Sent");
    });
});
```

Comment: The above errors doesn't come now. But apart from that the error " Parsing error: Unexpected token default" appears. What should be done for that?

Comment: right ... so what do **you** think `default` is ... what does it mean to you in that code? as you can't have a variable called `default`, should it be `"default"`, like I've done in the answer?

Answer (score -1):

You are using the reserved keyword `default` which you cannot use. I guess you meant to represent this as a string, e.g. `"default"`